# Kernel module compilation fails when installing vmware tools

Tags: installation, kernel, compiling, vmware

When I install WMWare tools, I get this error for vmhgfs:

```
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.c:47:28: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
make: *** [vmhgfs.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only'
If you wish to have the shared folders feature, you can install the driver by 
running vmware-config-tools.pl again after making sure that gcc, binutils, make
and the kernel sources for your running kernel are installed on your machine. 
These packages are available on your distribution's installation CD.
```

And `/mnt/hgfs` is empty when sharing. If I run `vmware-hgfsclient` in a terminal, I get the list of shared folders but `/mnt/hgfs` is empty.

i try to new version of vmware tools with vm machin but it very slowly And during the download is interrupted. can you give me link for tar.gz file?

Comment: Did you installed the kernel header for your running one ?

Answer (score 1):

I download this version:

VMwareTools-8.8.0-471268.tar.gz

The problem was solved

Comment: Yeah right, but how/where exactly did you get/download VMwareTools-8.8.0-471268.tar.gz!?? :( Just spent couple of hours looking for it and couldnt find anywhere... Any link would be of great help! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the previous versions here: http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/player/

This blog has some details on what to do if you are running VMware on a Windows host: http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/11/using-older-versions-of-vmware-tools.html